# Class in Module inherit a Class in module

Tags: python, inheritance, python-module

Hi I want that a class inherits from another class, both are modules.

modules

```
Main.py
mods/..
  __init__.py
  mod1
  mod2
```

**init**.py looks like this

```
from .mod1 import Class1
from .mod2 import Class2
```

mod1 is this

```
Class1():
      pass
```

mod2 is this

```
Class2(Class1)
    Pass
```

Main.py actually imports this

```
from mods import *
```

I get the error

```
NameError: name 'Class1' is not defined
```

What did I do wrong?
regards

Comment: Well, mod2 doesn't import Class1, so it is indeed not defined there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman doesnt init.py handle that?

Comment: Er, no. That is importing things into its own namespace only. You still need to define the names you are using at the point you are using them.